# Transverse Vibrations of a Cantilever beam. Why does the % change in nth natural frequency increases with n in this case?

Tags: frequency, vibrations, normal-modes, structural-beam

This is the problem in detail

I have a cantilever beam.

Now I am making it stand upright and adding water for different heights of **SUBMERGENCE**

I am doing this by adding an **ADDED MASS** term from the fixed end to the height **SUBMERGENCE** by taking the density until that height to be higher

[image]

For each value of **SUBMERGENCE** , I am finding the first 5 transverse natural frequencies of the beam with a **FIXED TIP MASS**

This is the resulting Graph

[image]

Here, X axis is **SUBMERGENCE** , Y axis is frequency

HERE, the line on top is the frequency values for 5th modeshape for varying **SUBMERGENCE**

Here, as **SUBMERGENCE** increases, the natural frequency of each modeshape decreases

the next line is that of the 4th modeshape and so on

Here,

The % difference between the highest and lowest frequency of **5th** modeshape is around **37%**

The % difference between the highest and lowest frequency of **4th** modeshape is around **33%**

The % difference between the highest and lowest frequency of **3rd** modeshape is around **27%**

The % difference between the highest and lowest frequency of **2nd** modeshape is around **24%**

The % difference between the highest and lowest frequency of **1st** modeshape is around **19%**

Can someone explain why does this **DECREASE** in the % difference happens when moving from 5th modeshape to 1st modeshape ??

THANKS

Comment: Could you explain what you do more clearly? I didn't understand. But if I can understand, I could give you some help

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, one thing is missing. How do you excited the structure? I suppose at bending, but it's better to ask. And to be sure, is the clamped end the lower one?

Comment: These are for free vibrations. Like the ones here https://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=3&brch=175&sim=1080&cnt=1